# How to write a function that notify me when someone mention me on irc in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, irc

I have this function

```
(defun mention-notify (match-type nickuserhost msg)
  (interactive)
  (if (and (eq match-type 'current-nick)
           (eq (string-match "^-NickServ-" msg) nil) ;this is probably not needed
           (eq (string-match "^\\*\\*\\*" msg) nil))
      (progn
        (shell-command "mpg123 -q /home/kuba/Pobrane/beep-8.mp3")
        (notify "ERC" msg))))

(add-hook 'erc-text-matched-hook 'mention-notify)
```

But it execute command even it message start from `***`. What I'm doing wrong here? How this function should look like?

I read [that page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ErcPageMe) but it only show how to send notification for all mentions, even from server. like:

`*** Users on #<chanel>: jcubic...`

or

`*** jcubic has changed mode for jcubic to +i`

It seams that when I check for `'current-nick` - msg is not the whole message but substring containing my nick, I try to check for keyword instead of current-nick and check if my nick that I always use appear in the text but using keyword doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied `erc-match-message` function from erc.el file into my .emacs file and I added one flag to hook

```el
(run-hook-with-args
 'erc-text-matched-hook
 (intern match-type)
 (or nickuserhost
     (concat "Server:" (erc-get-parsed-vector-type vector)))
 message
 (string-match "^\\*\\*\\*"
               (buffer-substring (point-min) (point-max)))))))
```

last flag is set if message is erc system message - starts with `***` so now I can check this flag in my hook

```el
(defun mention-notify (match-type nickuserhost msg notification)
  (interactive)
  (if (and (eq match-type 'current-nick)
           (not notification))
      (progn
        (shell-command "mpg123 -q /home/kuba/Pobrane/beep-8.mp3")
        (notify "ERC" msg))))
```

**UPDATE** I also didn't want to recive message from -NickServ- so I add this

```el
(run-hook-with-args
 'erc-text-matched-hook
 (intern match-type)
 (or nickuserhost
     (concat "Server:" (erc-get-parsed-vector-type vector)))
 message
 (let ((whole-msg (buffer-substring (point-min) (point-max))))
    (or (string-match "^-NickServ-" whole-msg)
        (string-match "^\\*\\*\\*" whole-msg)))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to look at Sauron:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Sauron

Comment: Nice, I will check it out. Maybe I will need to read ERC code or Sauron to have the answer to my question.

Comment: In all honesty, I'd recommend adopting `sauron`. It's young, but the author puts out all kinds of quality elisp.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search for ["erc mention notify"](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=erc+mention+notify&btnG=Google+Search&meta=) yields a [bunch of example code to do exactly what you want](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ErcPageMe).

Comment: Yes I read that page. I didn't run exact code But it check only if nick match so they should send notification when `*** server message appear` and I only wants mentions and not when I join chanel or login to the server.